# Netbeans how to add a JavaEE version?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans-8

I recently downloaded Glassfish 5 which is JavaEE 8 compliant, my problem now is that when I try to create a Java Web Application for e.g. I don't see the JavaEE 8 version available, only from JavaEE 5 - 7.

My {netbeans_install_path}/etc/netbeans.conf  is pointing to JDK 8:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"
```

How do I add JavaEE 8 to the options ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *How do I add JavaEE 8 to the options ?*

NetBeans does not have a Java EE 8 compatible version, yet.

NetBeans is like a glorified text editor with one million additional features, primarily code generators. What it can't autogenerate for you, you can just write yourself as if you were using Notepad like a hardcore programmer ;) Just pick Java EE 7 version, let Netbeans do its boring job of autogenerating the necessary files and then **manually** edit the location of [XML schema resources](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html#8) and versions yourself in the desired deployment descriptor files.

Servlet 4.0 `web.xml`:

```xml
<web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">
```

JSF 2.3 `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
    version="2.3">
```

Answer (score 4):

**Netbeans** > **File** > **New Project...**

Categories: **Maven** and Projects: **Project from Archetype**

**Next**

Search: **javaee8-essentials-archetype**

**Select** the searched entry

**Next**

and the rest is history.